# How to calculate is more than one second/hour passed using milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the time difference between two dates which have different format to know if more than one hour/seconds has passed.

The first format is: `2019-07-02T16:21:00.1030000`
The second one is: `1562160899773`

I am using `getMilliseconds()` but I don't know if it's the better way.

for example

```js
var isMoreOneSec = New Date(2019-07-02T16:21:00.1030000).getMilliseconds() - new Date(1562160899773).getMilliseconds() > 1000
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify/rephrase?

Answer (score 4):

`getMilliseconds()` will return the number of milliseconds in **the current second**, hence will always return from `0` to `999`, the same way `getHour()` will return from `0` to `23` or `getSeconds()` from `0` to `59`.

When you have two dates, to get the difference in milliseconds you have to use `getTime()` which will return the number of milliseconds sice unix epoch.

So:

```js
var date1 = new Date("2019-07-02T16:21:00.1030000");
var date2 = new Date(1562160899773);

var date1time = date1.getTime();
var date2time = date2.getTime();

console.log("Date 1 time is", date1time);
console.log("Date 2 time is", date2time);

var dif = date2time - date1time;

console.log("Dif in ms is ", dif);

console.log("Is dif more than one second?", dif > 1000);
console.log("Is dif more than one hour?", dif > 60*60*1000);
```